# Как установить правила безопасности в Firebase Realtime Database для конкретных параметров

Tags: firebase-database

В приложении используется Firebase Realtime Database. JSON выглядит примерно так:

```
"records": {
    "userId1": {
        "recordId1": {
            "playingCount": 11,
            "likeCount": 10,
            .
            .
            .
        "recordId2": {
            "playingCount": 11,
            "likeCount": 10,
            .
            .
            .   

    "userId2": {
        "recordId1": {
            "playingCount": 11,
            "likeCount": 10,
            .
            .
            .
```

Одна из главных веток называется `records`, там записаны данные о записях пользователях по следующей логике `records - userId - recordId`. В `recordId` есть разные параметры, в том числе `playingCount` и `likeCount`. Мне нужно прописать так правила безопасности, чтобы изменять (то есть '`write`') мог любой пользователь именно этих 2х параметров, а остальные не мог.
Пример: пользователь прослушивает запись друго пользователя и добавляет + 1 к счетчику прослушивания записи или ставит лайк и этот параметр тоже меняется в чужой записи.

Сейчас мои правила безопасности выглядят так:

```
"records" : { 
              "$uid" : {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid", 
                }
     },
```

но это не позволяет менять эти 2 параметра пользователю в ветке чужой записи.
Как мне прописать такие правила?

PS: разобрался как добавить правила для 1 параметра, но как туда вкруть второй пока не понятно (параллельно с `"$playingCount"` поставить такой же `"$likeCount"` не получается)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    
    "records": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          "$recordId": {
            "playingCount": {
              ".write": "auth != null",
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте пожалуйста документацию, там всё понятно написано

Comment: @Lesh Если вам не сложно, посмотрите дополнения к моему вопросу, мне осталось чуть-чуть до победы. Подскажите, пожалуйста